# Munin 2.0 vs 1.4

Tags: monitoring, munin

Munin came out with a new major release (2.0). It is, however, not easy to see what has changed. I've checked the [main site](http://munin-monitoring.org/), the [FAQ](http://munin-monitoring.org/wiki/faq) and the [Documentation](http://munin-monitoring.org/wiki/Documentation), but nothing found. There's the [Changelog](http://munin-monitoring.org/browser/munin/ChangeLog?rev=2.0.10), but that's too verbose to read. What I would like to know is

- What are the *main* changes / new features?
- Is it worth upgrading?

Comment: I've found two pages which are closer to what I'm looking for - but maybe somebody would like to share his experiences with upgrading from 1.4 to 2.0?

Answer (score 0):

I've found two helpful resources:

- [Wishlist](http://munin-monitoring.org/wiki/MuninPlans)
- [Announce 2.0](https://github.com/munin-monitoring/munin/blob/devel/Announce-2.0)

Answer (score 0):

Here you can find the official Munin 2.0 Announcement details:
https://github.com/munin-monitoring/munin/blob/2.0.0/Announce-2.0